# Pandas, match a pattern and replace

Tags: pandas, match

In a pandas dataframe I have a string `'2945'` anything in this column which is 4 numbers like this should be replaced as an error, in this example to `''`. Using regex the syntax for a `[0-9]` as `\d`. How do I get this to work?

```
gdf['montype'].str.match(pat =\d\d\d\d).replace('')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use directly the pandas **replace** function and specify the regex as argument.
Take a look to the doc: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html

In this way:

```
gdf = gdf.replace(to_replace='^[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]$',value='ERROR',regex=True)
```

If you just want to replace the 2945 value you can do this:

```
gdf = gdf.replace(to_replace='2945',value='ERROR')
```